# Using the builder pattern and Selenium to execute different searches with different combinations of criteria

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to automate some test cases around searching with multiple combinations of criteria. In my PageObject for my search page, I've created my Builder class as such

```
public class AdvancedSearchPage extends PageObject {

public static class Query {
        private WebDriver driver;

        private String commonName;
        private String contactEmail;
        private int certificateType;
        private int status;


        public Query(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
        }

        public Query setCommonName(String value) {
            this.commonName = value;
            return this;
        }

        public Query setContactEmail(String value) {
            this.contactEmail = value;
            return this;
        }

        public Query setCertificateType(int value) {
            this.certificateType = value;
            return this;
        }

        public Query setStatus(int value) {
            this.status = value;
            return this;
        }

         public AdvancedSearchPage build() {
            return new AdvancedSearchPage(driver,this);
        }
    }

    private AdvancedSearchPage(WebDriver driver, Query q) {
        super(driver);
        // Navigates to AdvancedSearchPage url and authenticates if necessary
        this.init(URL);

        this.setCommonName(q.commonName);
        this.setContactEmail(q.contactEmail);
        this.setCertificateType(q.certificateType);
        this.setStatus(q.status);

    }
}
```

In my private constructor, I take the values and use the `AdvancedSearchPage` object's 'setters' which simply sets the value for the relevant `WebElement`.

When I build a Query with just common name, the other fields are set. How can I modify the private constructor to only set the values of `WebElement`s that have been defined when building the Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean only set values of AdvancedSearchPage which are not null? If yes you can try this.

```
 private AdvancedSearchPage(WebDriver driver, Query q) {
    super(driver);
    // Navigates to AdvancedSearchPage url and authenticates if necessary
    this.init(URL);

    if(q.commonName != null) this.setCommonName(q.commonName);
    if(q.contactEmail != null) this.setContactEmail(q.contactEmail);
    if(q.certificateType != null) this.setCertificateType(q.certificateType);
    if(q.status != null) this.setStatus(q.status);

}
```

Comment: This was as simple as I thought the solution would end up being :) For the int's I had to use `0` instead of `null` and ensure no certificate types or statuses were represented by `0`.

Comment: This defeats much of the purpose of the builder pattern in that you can't chain these together. See the top couple answers here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/241309/builder-pattern-when-to-fail.